# Is there a Reliable and Current Resource Listing Browser / Browser Version Bugs Available Anywhere?

Tags: html, css, browser, browser-bugs

I was surprised to be unable to find a solid resource that documents browser CSS, HTML and Javascript bugs. Obviously there are sites like http://caniuse.com/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/ which take things from the other direction, documenting feature implementation and sometimes noting bugs and partially implemented features, but is there a site which lists known bugs and workarounds on a per-browser/browser version basis?

Comment: Probably not, since most people are trying to solve a specific problem/bug, not looking for a listing of all problems to avoid.  I think that would be pretty overwhelming.

Comment: [Not exactly what you want, but here's an IE specific page](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html).

Comment: This post from Paul Irish helps document hacks and bugs for HTML/CSS - http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Comment: Probably list of stable universal cross-browser patterns for common tasks can be more useful than list of bugs, but also can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

I find 
http://caniuse.com/

incredibly useful for knowing which features are supported by which browsers. Hope this helps

Comment: caniuse.com is indispensable, but it comes at things from the opposite end.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things slightly easier to find, here are resources suggested so far in the comments:

> http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

– IE 5+ bugs, though not updated since 2009

> http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks

– Paul Irish's list of common browser hacks, again not updated since 2009.

Answer (score 0):

What I found pretty interesting are the different doctypes. Not only that you can trigger QuirksMode (an IE 5.5-like rendering in InternetExplorer - don't know how other browsers handle that) but also that you can have an Almost-Standard-Mode. http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#Sending%20XHTML%20as%20text/html%20Considered%20Harmful

Here's a list of bugs in IE8: http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs

All the other stuff I found is most likely gone. IE6 is nearly dead (http://www.ie6countdown.com/#chart), IE7 is also used by just a minority (http://theie7countdown.com/) ... now it's just depending on what you want to support. If you still want/have to support IE7 or IE6, I'd look at the links posted by Pedr. That's where I found all the css-bugs, excepted by one - the IE6 PNG bug. But Safari also has his problems with the PNG transparency and the gamma channel :)

PNG Problem (IE6, IE7 and Safari): http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/articles/png-gamma.html

That's all coming to my mind. I mostly skip the PNG problem by minifying the png and gif files before uploading them into a live-system by using http://imageoptim.com/.

I don't know if anyone listed the JS-Bugs ... I just know of missing functions and that's where you could use a framework like jQuery or something not that blown-up :)